# Only enable landscape in some specific ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

My app has many different ViewController, I want to allow some specific ViewController can rotate landscape. I have tried some way like using supportedInterfaceOrientations or shouldAutorotate, but it does not work.
Is there anyone have other ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update in your ViewController is not enough, you must update more in AppDelegate.

AppDelegate

```
var enableAllOrientation = false
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if enableAllOrientation {
        return .all
    }
    return .portrait
}
```

Any ViewController that you want support landscape, just implement:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    appDelegate?.enableAllOrientation = true
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    appDelegate?.enableAllOrientation = false
}
```

Comment: why do we need appdelegate instance creation?  make it global enableAllOrientation